# Using "map to another variable" in IDA

Tags: ida, ghidra

I am using in IDA. There is a feature which is called "map to another variable".
but it asks from me to map from the variable from a list. How do u know the exact variable to map into ? (I can assume which variable, but it could be a mistake and continuing in reverse engineering the program could lead to mistakes in next). In Ghidra, it figures the correct variable by itself.

1. Are there any tips for IDA users ?
2. Is there any automation for IDA like in Ghidra ?